# Laravel DataBase Connection: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I install laravel on Ampps (windows 10) with .

it works.

But Now I want connect to mysql.

I create a 'blog' DB and change these two files:
.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD='mysql'
```

and /config/database.php :

```
  'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'blog'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'mysql'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

but still I get the below message when I want to migrate:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\blog>php artisan migrate
>
> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations)
>
> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Please include the error message instead of posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Password should be this

```
DB_PASSWORD=mysql
```

Not this

```
DB_PASSWORD='mysql'
```

Comment: It worked for me on namecheap. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should write this

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

and your env file is

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mysql
```

Also restart your server.

Answer (score 1):

First change your password in .env file from `DB_PASSWORD='mysql'` to `DB_PASSWORD=mysql` without single quotation. Second you should set more secure passwords for your databases.

You should give root user access to your database.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON blog.* TO 'root'@'localhost' identified by 'mysql';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: This was it for me. I changed servers and the db user could read and write but not alter tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try running below command

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

This should update the settings saved in the cache.